# Error when testing exceptions with phpunit

Tags: php, phpunit

I am trying to test this function :

```
/**
 * @expectedException     InvalidArgumentException
 * @expectedExceptionMessage Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
 */
function testSetAdsData_dataIsNull()
{
    $dataArr = null;
    $fixture = new AdGroup();

    $fixture->setAdsData($dataArr);
}
```

But I get this error in my console:

There was 1 error:

```
1) adGroupTest::testSetAdsData_dataIsNull
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

/home/al/tests/adserver/src/classes/AdGroup.php:31
/home/al/tests/adserver/test/classes/AdGroupTest.php:65

FAILURES!
Tests: 15, Assertions: 23, Errors: 1.
```

Wasn't the `@expectedExceptionMessage` supposed to keep me safe from getting this error? Or am I missing something else?

Comment: `Error` !== `Exception` Change your `setAdsData()` method to test whether the supplied argument is a valid array or not, and throw an `InvalidArgumentException` if it isn't

Comment: Add this to your `setAdsData` method: `if (!$argument) throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Invalid argument supplied for foreach()');`. If the setter doesn't actually throw an exception, then of course your test won't be successful. Besides: tests aren't meant to ignore syntax/runtime errors